# Equivalent of C++ shift operator << in Java?

Tags: java, c++, porting

C++ shift operator `<<` does not cycle. For example if you do:

```
// C++
int a = 1;
cout << (a<<38);
```

You get 0. But, in Java you actually cycle and get a valid value of 64.

I need to translate some C++ code to Java, so what do I use as the equivalent for `<<`?

Comment: Just as a note, if `a` is 32 bits wide, then `a << 38` is actually undefined behavior in C or C++. _C++ 2011 Section 5.8 Paragraph 1_.

Comment: What sharth says - this means the best way to implement the operator in Java would involve returning random stuff (and sometimes aborting the runtime) when we shift more than the bitwidth of the datatype... not exactly sure how useful that'd be though.

Answer (score 9):

The [Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) states:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f
>   (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the
>   range 0 to 31, inclusive.
>
> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is long, then only the
>   six lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x3f
>   (0b111111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in
>   the range 0 to 63, inclusive.

So, in your example case, `(int)(((long)a)<<38)` should work.

Comment: or `(a << (38 % sizeof(a)))`, which is a bit more type safe. (A long doesn't need to be bigger than an int).

Comment: The C++ spec actually says something along these same lines.  Only a few values are valid on the right hand side of `<<`, the rest are undefined behavior.

Comment: @sharth - In Java an int is 32 bits and a long is 64.  Very rigidly defined.

Comment: @HotLicks: Oops. I thought we were pushing the code in the other direction for a minute there. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits
>   of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand
>   operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the
>   mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in
>   the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

Please refer to Java Language Specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7-diffs.pdf