# Shift Operator in Java

Tags: java, bit-shift

How does the shift operator `<<` work when the value of the shift bits is greater than the total number of bits for the datatype?

For example,

```
int i = 2; 
int j = i<<34;
System.out.println(j);
```

The size of an integer is 32 bits, however we are shifting 34 bits. How does this work?

Comment: What does the output say?

Comment: `i << 34 = i << 2` :) *what goes around comes around*.

Comment: I asked this question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15708760/1280997

Comment: They `float` off the end of the `Integer` and accumulate on the `Math.ceiling()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you shift an integer with the << or >> operator and the shift distance is greater than or equal to 32, you take the shift distance mod 32 (in other words, you mask off all but the low order 5 bits of the shift distance).

This can be very counterintuitive. `For example (i >> 32) == i`, for every integer i. You might expect it to shift the entire number off to the right, returning 0 for positive inputs and -1 for negative inputs, but it doesn't; it simply returns i, because 
`(i << (32 & 0x1f)) == (i << 0) == i`.

Getting back to your original problem, (i << 33) == (i << (33 & 0x1f))
== (i << 1). You can do the whole thing in binary if you like. 270 in binary is : 0000  0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 1110 Shifting right by 1, 
you get: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0111 which is 135.

But a better way to do this problem in your head is to dispense with the binary entirely. 
The value of `i >> s is floor(i / 2<sup>s</sup>)` (where s has already been masked off so it's less than 32). So,  `270 << 1 = floor(270/2) = 135`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19

Comment: You should format this better.  Making it more readable is never a bad thing.

Comment: why we don't have a signed left shift operator(in java) ?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure the source on this, but according to [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_Java) (emphasis mine):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the **five
>   lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift
>   distance**. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a
>   bitwise logical AND operator & with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111).[4]
>   The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to
>   31, inclusive.

**Edit:**  It looks like the WikiPedia entry basically lifted the information straight out of the [Java Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).

Answer (score 1):

If you try `1 << 34`, you end up with `4`. The runtime basically has an implicit `mod NUMBER_OF_BITS` on the right-hand operand of the shift. In the previous example, it's `1 << (34 % 32)`, which becomes `1 << 2`, which is 4.